# Symfony Regex validator doesn't work in annotation

Tags: symfony, symfony-validator

I'm building an application on **Symfony 3.2**

On one part of the application I'm providing an interface my users to change their passwords. For this task, I have a simple form which bound to my `ChangePasword` entity as follows.

**Form class:**

```
namespace MasterBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ChangePasswordType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('oldPassword', PasswordType::class)
            ->add('newPassword', PasswordType::class);
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'data_class' => 'MasterBundle\Entity\ChangePassword'
            )
        );
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'change_password';
    }
}
```

**And the model:**

```
<?php

namespace MasterBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Validator\Constraints\UserPassword;

class ChangePassword
{

    /**
     * @UserPassword(message="Your current password is not correct.")
     */
    private $oldPassword;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="New password can not be blank.")
     * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\d).{6,}$/i", message="New password is required to be minimum 6 chars in length and to include at least one letter and one number.")
     */
    private $newPassword;

// other setter and getter stuff.
}
```

Now, the problem is the regex validator doesn't work. It doesnt match with anything.

However, if I modify the model as below; it works flawlessly:

```
<?php

namespace MasterBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Validator\Constraints\UserPassword;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;

class ChangePassword
{

    private $oldPassword;

    private $newPassword;

public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
{
    $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('oldPassword', new Userpassword(array(
        'message' => 'Your current password is not correct.',
    )));

    $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('newPassword', new Assert\NotBlank(array(
        'message' => 'New password can not be blank.',
    )));

    $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('newPassword', new Assert\Regex(array(
        'pattern' => '/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\d).{6,}$/i',
        'message' => 'New password is required to be minimum 6 chars in length and to include at least one letter and one number.'
    )));
}

// other setter and getter stuff.
}
```

Do you have any idea about the root of this problem? Any idea about further debugging the case, would be appreciated.

Comment: check the `config.yml` files and verify you have the line `validation:      { enable_annotations: true }`  under the framework key.

Comment: @Matteo Yes it is enabled, moreover `Assert\NotBlank` annotation works as expected ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that for this specific regular expression, the one in the annotation should not escape `\d` bit, however in the PHP implementation (ie using `loadValidatorMetadata`) we need to escape it.

If I edit the model which implemented the constraint in annotation as follows, it works:

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="New password can not be blank.")
 * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).{6,}$/i", message="New password is required to be minimum 6 chars in length and to include at least one letter and one number.")
 */
private $newPassword;
```

Just edit `/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\d).{6,}$/i` to `/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).{6,}$/i`

This seems to inconsistent. I think the annotation, yaml, xml and PHP implementations need to be identical whereas possible, the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html) should emphasize all of the inconsistencies.

Therefore I [raised an issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/22865) on Symfony repo.